# Use ffmpeg to split a file output by size

Tags: ffmpeg

I can split an aid (or video) file by time, but how do I split it by file size?

`ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -ss S -to E -c copy output1.mp3 -ss S -to E -c copy output2.mp3`

Which is fine if I have time codes, but if I want the output files to be split at 256MB regardless of the time length, what do I do? (What I am doing now is estimating, but that often means I have to make multiple runs at it with `-ss S -to E` to get files that are close to where I want in size).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38259544/using-ffmpeg-to-split-video-files-by-size

Comment: wow. searched for ffmpeg file size and that di not come up. So, not possible in ffmpeg itself, but possible with a wrapper script. That will work, was hoping to avoid that, but it will work. (well, the script does not work with current ffmpeg, but is probably fixable)

Comment: Do you want the pieces to be valid mp3 files? If not, the `split` command will do this for you.

Comment: Does it have to be `ffmpeg`? If not, also have a look at `mp3splt`, which (a) does not re-encode and (b) has better splitting options, though I haven't seen a "file size" method. And if your mp3 has constant bitrate, a 256MB should have a given number of frames, so you can split on number of frames, or time length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option you are looking for is `-fs` which limits the file size.

here is the official documentation: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options

Comment: pleace tell me the whole command which i should type.